# Floating Button with context menu and form on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create html form which will be floating on top of content. Button will be floating on content and on click of each button different div form  should appear below. Something like in below screen shot. It shows button only on first appearance and on click of each button below form should append and appear. In case on last button, context menu with additional button should appear.

I have tried to create buttons and forms, but how to :

1) Add give button kind of look to button1, button2 ...which is div

2) On click show context menu on last button

3) Hide and show appropriate form on click of corresponding button

[jsbin](https://jsfiddle.net/k1dkb8fe/)
[image]

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FBBC06;
}

#form {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  right: 168px;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  border-radius: 22px;
}

.widthHeight {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#button1 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
#button2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#button4{
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#button5 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 12%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#form1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

#form2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

#form3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widthHeight">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="form">
        <div id="buttonHolder">
            <div id="button1">
                button1
            </div>
            <div id="button2">
                buton2
            </div>
            <div id="button3">
                button3
            </div>
            <div id="button4">
                button4
            </div>
            <div id="button5">
                button5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form1">
            This is form 1 on click of button 1 it appears
        </div>
        <div id="form2">
            This is form 1 on click of button 1 it appears
        </div>
        <div id="form3">
            This is form 1 on click of button 1 it appears
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should look up the css `display: none`. Using it in conjunction with `display: block` should easily get what you desire.

Comment: What CSS should I add in button to look like button which is clickable . Its just div now

Comment: Well what I meant by the css is that you would use javascript to trigger the css changes (using jquery for simplicity, not necessary), e.g. `$("#button1").click( () => $("#form1").css('display', 'block') )` I'll take a look again when I'm home if you still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Personalize CSS - up to your personal taste. Changing the background color and/or cursor might add the effect you need, so something like

```
.divbutton:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

should help you. (add `class='divbutton'` to each div acting as a button)

3)
Create these style classes

```
.hiddenitem
    {
      display:none;
    }

.shownitem
    {
      display:block;
    }
```

add `.hidenitem` class to each form

```
<div id="form1" class="hiddenitem">
    This is form 1 on click of button 1 it appears 
</div>
```

in your script file or tag

```
activateMenu = function (menuId)
{
     $("#form" + menuId).toggleClass('shownitem');
}
```

finally add `onclick='activateMenu(menuId)'` to each corresponding button

```
<div id="button2" onclick='activateMenu(2)'>
                                    TEXT1
</div>
```

For 2) use the same approach as for the forms: Create the context menu in html, apply the `.hidenitem` class and create a toggle function to toggle `.shownitem` class on the menu, using its own id as selector.

Edit:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e05zv46e/2/)

Comment: Also i am not able to give button kind of effect , what css should I add to looks div as press able .

Comment: Added the Fiddle. That's really pretty much up to you and a design question. This can help you https://dabuttonfactory.com/ (get css in embed)

Comment: Thank you , can you make this look better in you jsfiddle

Comment: Perhaps, but if this answers your question you should accept it ;)

Comment: Updated JSFiddle link with better visual interface, it now links to Bootstrap cdn.